# Asp.net MVC : Registerstartupscript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How to use Registerstartupscript in my project ? Is it any soluction for that ?

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET MVC, you have full control over the markup being produced. If you need a script to be included on the page, simply do it using vanilla HTML/JavaScript.

There really should be no need for RegisterStartupScript in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here **http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38936/Using-WebControls-In-ASP-NET-MVC-Views-Part-3.aspx**

Answer (score 0):

inHTML Code :

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcTest.HelperExtension" %>
<script src="<%= Url.jQueryUI("jquery.ui.accordion.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

.
.
.
.

in Code :

```
public static class UrlHelperExtension
{  

    public static string jQuery(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
    {
        return helper.Content(string.Format("~/Content/Scripts/{0}", fileName));
    } 

}
```

Comment: See This Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628611/asp-net-mvc-3-partial-view-dynamically-rendered-and-linked-from-dynamic-list-in