# ASP.NET MVC 3 Partial View dynamically rendered and linked from dynamic list in view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, partial-views

In my MVC 3 application, I will have a view that will contain a partial view. The view itself will have a list of dynamically generated links. The link has to cause the partial view to render detailed information for that linked item.

Would I use Ajax for this? If so, since I haven't worked with Ajax before, is there any documentation for using it in a MVC 3 app?

Also when the view is first loaded, the partial view will either not be loaded or ideally show another separate partial view. Any thoughts on a good way of doing this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest way of solving this problem that I found was using Ajax helpers that come with the MVC 3 framework. The Ajax video for MVC 3 on [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro) did a phenomenal job at succinctly explaining the basics of how to use this feature.

Answer (score 10):

Create an **action method** which returns a **PartialViewResult:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DetailedLinkInfo(int someIdentifier)
{
   var detailedLinkInfo = GetFromSomewhere();
   return PartialView(detailedLinkInfo );
}
```

Then create a **partial view**, strongly-typed to the type of **detailedLinkInfo** (let's say it's an `DynamicLink`.

```
@model WebApplication.Models.DynamicLink
@* bunch of HTML for the detailed info *@
```

Then use **jQuery** on the client-side. Give all your links a class so it makes it easier to hook up the event:

```
$(function() {
   $('a.dynamic-link').click(function() {
      $.get('/SomeController/DetailedLinkInfo', someIdentifier: $(this).attr('id'), function(data) {
         $('#some-div').html(data);
      });
   });
});
```

End result: you click one of the links, the jQuery will perform an AJAX GET to your controller action, then bind the result to the div.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however i went with the ajax helpers that come with MVC3

Comment: @James - no problems. You should know though that as of MVC 3, the AJAX helpers and JS library (MicrosoftMvcAjax.js) is considered "legacy" now. jQuery does it all - saves you having an extra JS library. Totally up to you though.